# CSS custom checkboxes float something to exact left

Tags: css, checkbox, label

I've got a styled checkbox where I want to have a link next to the label. The labels have different widths so I can't put the link relative to the left. Due to the styled checkbox I can't 'detect' the width of the label with css.
So to make it clear, in the jsfiddle I've made I want the link info to be to the left of the label.

http://jsfiddle.net/SAZ2P/3/

Cheers!

css:

```
.selectbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.selectbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.selectbox label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-indent: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.selectbox label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    height: 4px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 2px;
    left: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.selectbox label:hover::after {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.selectbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.selectbox a{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You don't detect the width of anything with CSS- you use JavaScript.

Comment: yes that's why I've put 'detect'. I had a hard time explaining this haha. BTW I don't think this is something that should be solved with JS

Comment: I think a diagram of what you want would help. Also, styling checkboxes is not stable across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to include the link inside of the label.  For example:

```
<div class="selectbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="brand2" id="brand2" name="brand2" class="box">
    <label for="brand2"><a href="/link" id="brand_info">info</a> brand with longer name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I thought that if I did that the checkbox would be clicked automatically but it doesn't. Obvious solution ftw :)